# Adding Carriage Return <CR> and CTRL-Z to a String in java

Tags: java

I am working to send SMS using java program.

The AT command is supping as a string. But the string format should be like
`AT+CMGS="+33146290800"<CR>Please call me soon.<ctrl-Z>`.

I have to create string with the Carriage Return and CTRL-Z character.

#### If I add 0x0D and 0x1A with the string.

output:

```
AT+CMGS="+33146290800"13Please call me soon.26
```

How can I achieve the task? Can anyone help me to find a way out.

Comment: Carriage return should be `\r`. What character is `<ctrl-z>`?

Comment: @Jens To sending sms by AT command you need to press ctrl+z

Comment: For `<ctrl-z>` try \032`

Comment: But how to concatenate it with string.

Comment: I think thats it AT+CMGS="+33146290800\rPlease call me soon\032"

Comment: Thanks for asking this.  I've been working on the same thing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get this string:

```
"+33146290800"<CR>Please call me soon.<ctrl-Z>
```

You use this string literal:

```
String s = "\"+33146290800\"\rPlease call me soon.\u001A";
```

`\"` is the Java string literal escape sequence for a double quote, `\r` is escape sequence a carriage return, and `\u0026` is the Java string literal Unicode escape sequence for character x1A (decimal 26), e.g., Ctrl+Z. [More to explore in the JLS.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5)